# SQL Results Not Returned to C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

SETUP:

- asp.net MVC
- SQL SERVER 2008 R2

I have a procedure to get a list of messages to send.  I want to update the results records so I cannot accidentally pull the same records twice.  Regardless of how I approach it, `SSMS` produces the correct list of messages.  However, if I update the records in the same procedure, C# does not get any results.

I have tried using a `DataAdapter` like this:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(table);
```

and `DataReader` like this:

```
var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
table.Load(dataReader);
dataReader.Close();
```

to populate my `DataTable`, neither seems to affect the results.

My procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MnxNoticeGetMessages] 
@sessionId uniqueidentifier = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Output TABLE (messageid uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO @Output
SELECT messageid FROM MnxTriggerEmails WHERE dateSent is null 

SELECT * FROM MnxTriggerEmails WHERE messageid IN (SELECT messageid FROM @Output)

UPDATE MnxTriggerEmails SET dateSent=GETDATE() 
    WHERE messageid IN (SELECT * FROM @Output)
END
```

This produces results in `SSMS` but not in `C#`.

If I comment out the `UPDATE` like this (no other changes):

```
--UPDATE MnxTriggerEmails SET dateSent=GETDATE() 
--    WHERE messageid IN (SELECT * FROM @Output)
```

I get the expected results in both `SSMS` and `C#`.

What am I missing?  What would cause this?  How do I update the records AND get the results at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `Read()` method of `dataReader` to debug your code?

Comment: No, are you thinking that the select method affects how the DataReader uses and loads the info? I don't get errors, I just don't get results in the datatable.

Comment: Have you tried moving the select after the update?

Comment: Yes, the order didn't make a difference. I just don't get why the results look identical in ssms, but not in c#.

Comment: Try adding a `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your procedure.

Comment: `NOCOUNT ON` is already implemented.

Comment: Whats in the `....`? Either post it, or remove it and test again.

Comment: I added it to indicate that I removed much of the processing code that does not affect the results.  I have removed the `...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  It should work.  It almost sounds like you are calling the sp twice.  The first time changes the dates and the second returns no results.  This would cause ssms to produce the desired results and c# to be empty.

Check the code you haven't posted and see if you make that call again before populating the DataTable.

Comment: now I feel silly for spending so much time.  I called the sp as a dataset, then returned the datatable.